# How can I watch a windows folder from my Ubuntu VM know which file has changed?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I need to know which files have been updated in a Windows folder from my Ubuntu VM. I have a symlink of the folder I want to watch.

What I found that is the closest to my needs is this python program called [rerun](https://github.com/tartley/rerun).

So I'll cd into my watchfolder and use `rerun -v "myscript.sh"`. The `v` option will output the updated files in the terminal but I don't know how to send this output to `myscript.sh`

Any idea? (even outside of this rerun thing)

Comment: Call `rerun` from within your script, process the output.

Comment: I don't know how to make it work. It's my first bash script. I think what makes it hard is that `rerun` is keeping the shell hostage until I `ctrl+c` because it needs to watch files. I don't know how to manage that in a script.
The best I could do for now is run the command in a shell like this `rerun -v : >> filestocheck.txt` and in another script that I could run with a `crontab` or  `watch` I would use the content of `filestocheck.txt`. But I need to manually stop the `rerun` process if I want my `filestocheck.txt` to be updated... in other words, it's no good haha

Comment: Use `$(somecommand)` or pipes (`|`) to process the output of some command with anther. Also there is no need to use separate scripts, as one single script will run each command sequentially anyways. Nobody will write "your" first bash script for you, if you are unable to do what you want to, go on the internet and learn about the topic.

Comment: Ye well... I've already tried using `|` and `$(command)`, with success for usual commands but this `rerun` thing is something else. The way it works is `rerun [options] command`. I don't know how to get the console output of the `-v` option because the `|` will use the result of my `command`. That's why I ended up using the null command `:` and redirecting all that into a text file. I wouldn't have found this without going on the internet and trying to learn about the topic, I'm actually stuck here. Maybe I lack the keywords, I'm probably trying to create something that already exists.

Comment: superuser.com is not for programming questions and also not for requesting learning material. There are multiple ways of doing this and I'm sure you will figure it out at some point, but with the amount of information you've provided nobody would be able to help you anyways.

Comment: True it's not for programming, but even if I talked about `rerun`, I think my question didn't ask for programming advice, I was just asking for a solution. We ended up discussing about programming though.

Anyway, I've finally found my solution, thank you for trying to help me though.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who can't use inotifywait because it doesn't work when the files are on windows, I just found someone who made another version with polling, and it works!

[inotifywait-polling by javanile](https://github.com/javanile/inotifywait-polling)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).